# the form is behind the buttons

Tags: c#, forms

I have a MDI form and it has buttons and I want to open other
form when I click on the buttons in the MDI but when I do that
the new form is behind the buttons as seen in the below image (the buttons in the MDI is a panel)

[image]

I need the 
new form in front the button. How can I do that? or if it´s 
impossible,are there other solutions?

Comment: It's impossible to see from that horrific image what you're talking about. Can you do a proper screen capture, instead of a photo from your phone, so that it's at least useful? Also, as a general rule MDI should consist of one parent with a menu or toolbar (with all of the buttons on that toolbar) and an open area where the child forms are displayed. Based on the ragged bunch of stuff I see in the upper left corner,, that''s not what you have here.

Comment: the design if from my boss so we tried to make it work but when we open others windows from the aplications the are behind the buttons (I´m not at the office so they send me this picture)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a Panel to the main portion of your MDI and then move all your existing Buttons into it.  Now **Dock** that Panel to the Left side of the MDI form.  Your MDI Child Forms should now properly occupy the space left behind in the main portion of the MDI Form.